# What is the source of Mathematica's maps? How do I cite them?

Tags: curated-data, reference-request, licensing

I used `GeoListPlot` to generate a beautiful map and included it in a paper I submitted to a journal. I cited the link http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/ in my paper as the source, but the journal editor has asked me to cite the source in the figure's caption according to Wolfram Mathematica's terms of use (http://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica.html).

Please tell me where is the world map from.

Comment: [This question on referencing Wolfram resources](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92179/form-of-citation-for-data-via-wolfram-mathematica?s=2|0.0897) (_Form of citation for data via Wolfram Mathematica_), while not conclusive, might be of some use.

Comment: If you are asking in multiple places please mention this and link question to prevent effort duplication.

Comment: 99% sure the data is sourced from Open Street Maps

Comment: "but the journal editor has asked me to cite the source in the figure's caption according to Wolfram Mathematica's terms of use" <- Don't the terms of use just tell you to cite Mathematica itself?  I am not saying that you shouldn't find out where Mathematica took the data from, but I do not see how this would be required by the terms of use.

Comment: So, you should contact Wolfram Technical Support (support@wolfram.com) and ask them to get an official answer.  @Mike Honeychurch is correct that some mapping capabilities come from Open Street Maps which (as far as I understand does not constitute legal advice of any kind) requires you to cite them in your work.

Comment: FWIW `In[16]:= Options[GeoListPlot[Here], MetaInformation]
Out[16]= {MetaInformation -> {"Software" -> "Wolfram Language", "TileSources" -> "Wolfram Knowledgebase with data from OpenStreetMap"}}`